# MySQL Benchmark on FreeBSD and Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, performance, benchmark

I'd like to benchmark two db servers, one is running Ubuntu the other FreeBSD. Unfortunately we are unable to install [SysBench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/) on the FreeBSD OS. Could anyone recommend any alternatives? Or should I look into creating some intense queries based on the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlslap.html) to run a number of different test cases.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile correctly SysBench 0.5 on a FreeBSD system you have to download the source code from [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/) ([SysBench v0.5](https://launchpad.net/sysbench)), see [bug 1029088](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sysbench/+bug/1029088)

Then, for benchmarking purposes, you can take a look into this post:

- [Stress test MySQL with queries captured with general log in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/stress-test-mysql-with-queries-captured-with-general-log-in-mysql)

Or you can use the standard oltp test provided by SysBench