# Stress test MySQL with queries captured with general log in MySQL

Tags: mysql, logs, scalability, performance, performance-testing

Is there any tool available which can do stress testing using the log file created by MySQL general log?
After a lot of search on google I found few stress testing tools which only use some benchmarks for stress test. One solution is using Apache JMeter, but it does not create test plans from MySQL log file and creating custom test plan for all the queries I have is too time consuming.

Or is there a tool which can at least create .sql file from MySQL log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is only a trace not a complete solution, "your" solution is based on your fantasy (and some work) ;)**

I have done this kind of test capturing and cleaning query generated by the general query log and using [sysbench 0.5](https://code.launchpad.net/~sysbench-developers/sysbench/0.5) after writing my own `lua` file, you can find some samples in the official [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sysbench-developers/sysbench/0.5/files/head:/sysbench/tests/db/), on a mirror of my database(hw and schema/data -a snapshot so I can restore the original status of data immediately- ).

Then you can run a command like this:

`./sysbench --mysql-table-engine=myisam --mysql-db=<yourdb> --mysql-user=<user> --mysql-host=<host> --mysql-password=<pass> --test=tests/db/<yourlua>.lua --num-threads=8 --max-requests=8 run`

Collect and graph your results, changing concurrency and requests, and monitor your database and HW status.

My `lua` file contains about 80.000 query and it is composed by insert, update and  delete

### UPDATE #1

A good starting point that you can try is to start (simply) writing your `lua` file like this:

```
pathtest = string.match(test, "(.*/)") or ""

dofile(pathtest .. "common.lua")

function thread_init(thread_id)
   set_vars()

   if (db_driver == "mysql" and mysql_table_engine == "myisam") then
      -- begin_query = "LOCK TABLES ".. table_name .." WRITE"
      -- commit_query = "UNLOCK TABLES"
      begin_query = "SELECT 1>0"
      commit_query = "SELECT 1>0"
   else
      begin_query = "BEGIN"
      commit_query = "COMMIT"
   end
end

function event(thread_id)
    local table_name
    db_query(begin_query)
    rs = db_query("INSERT INTO .....")
    rs = db_query("INSERT INTO .....")
    rs = db_query("SELECT ... FROM ...")
    rs = db_query("DELETE ...")
    db_query(commit_query)
end
```

Putting your query into the `db_query("")` function, ***cleaning your general query log for this kind of process require a bit of work***

Here a simple output of a "personal" `lua` file, like the above, with 9 query, 7 insert and 2 select, +2 BEGIN/COMMIT:

```
sysbench 0.5:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 8
Random number generator seed is 0 and will be ignored


Threads started!

OLTP test statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            32
        write:                           56
        other:                           0
        total:                           88
    transactions:                        0      (0.00 per sec.)
    deadlocks:                           0      (0.00 per sec.)
    read/write requests:                 88     (7728.11 per sec.)
    other operations:                    0      (0.00 per sec.)

General statistics:
    total time:                          0.0114s
    total number of events:              8
    total time taken by event execution: 0.0252s
    response time:
         min:                                  2.87ms
         avg:                                  3.15ms
         max:                                  3.65ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               3.65ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           1.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   0.0032/0.00
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know anything about `lua` files. How can I create `lua` files from my log files? If I am not wrong just renaming .log to .lua wont work.

Comment: @RuchitRami, see my update

Comment: Hmm, this will require me to manually add my queries to code in `lua` file. It is exactly what i was trying to avoid. Your solution would work for sure, but I was looking for a method to get sql script from log file. For stress test by copying queries manually, I am sure i can work it out with Apache JMeter. But thank anyway for your answer, got something new to learn.

Comment: not at all! I posted "my" solution ;) ... I have included in my update a sample output of `sysbench`

Comment: Hi, after following your steps I am getting error `Invalid test name: tests/db/mysqltest.lua`. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Hi, try using the full path to your test file `/home/<user>/path/to/your/tests/db/mysqltest.lua`

Comment: Tried full path, but still same error. Do I need to do anything other than just copy the lua file to the path?

Comment: Wich version of sysbech ?

Comment: sysbench-0.4.12. It was the latest one from sourceforge.

Comment: can you share your full sysbench command? ps: I have insalled the 0.5 version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8396/discussion-between-ruchit-rami-and-cristian-porta)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more direct approach using brute force mysql: Setup the general as a MyISAM table. On installation, you will find the table `mysql.general_log` as a CSV table.

Rather than reinventing the wheel and doing a whole lot of typing, please read my past posts:

- `Nov 16, 2011` : [Log MySQL DB changing queries and users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7985/log-mysql-db-changing-queries-and-users/7987#7987)
- `Feb 11, 2012` : [MySQL general log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log/12672#12672)
- `Jan 08, 2012` : [How to enable MySQL general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log/10346#10346)

Once you get `mysql.general_log` converted to MyISAM and queries are getting recorded, simply access the log like any other MyISAM table.

Here is the structure of the MyISAM version of `mysql.general_log`

```
mysql> show create table mysql.general_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: general_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `event_time` (`event_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

From here, just write all content starting with a query:

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT argument FROM mysql.general_log"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE LEFT(argument,6) IN"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','SELECT')"
mysql -uroot -p -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > SQLCommands.sql
```

There you go.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Great! It would have taken me few days to figure this out, and I am not sure if i could have reached to such neat solution.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, Thanks! I had not thought to pick up the query using this way, so I can avoid working directly and manually on the mysql general log file! Building my lua file from mysql.general_log is surely more simple and fast... +1

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, This really helps!! 
Also can i get the DB used for each query?  I am not using the fully qualified table name from code and most like the queries will fail.