# MySQL slap with custom query

Tags: mysql, mysqlslap

I want to conduct stress test on our MySQL DB. I have the list of queries i need to execute. I have tried using Apache JMeter for this but it is very time consuming. Is it possible to run mysqlslap with custom .sql file containing INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT queries on specified MySQL database?

Comment: see the `--query` option

Comment: `--query` option allows only `SELECT` statements as mentioned here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html#option_mysqlslap_query

Comment: Try changing your stress test tool, if you can, take a look on my answer here:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/stress-test-mysql-with-queries-captured-with-general-log-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqlslap --query` option will absolutely take a file containing lines with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and REPLACE INTO statements, as well as SELECT.

In fact, one of the examples later in the documentation shows it taking an INSERT:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html#option_mysqlslap_number-of-queries